# Check Whether a DIV Reaches it End on Window Scroll in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div of dynamic content so it height depends on dynamic data. when i scroll the browser window to bottom, if the that div reaches its end (bottom) on the view, i want to trigger a function (for now just console it ('reached bottom of div')). Also if browser reached the end of the page, the same function wants to trigger.  how to achieve this im new to JS and innerHeight, clientHeight so on.. are confusing.

```css
body {
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.dynamicDiv {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="dynamicDiv">
  some Dynamic data
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

window.innerHeight property returns the height of a window's content area.
window.scrollY returns the number of pixels that the document is currently scrolled vertically.
document.body.offsetHeight returns body's height including padding and border

https://jsfiddle.net/smilingpigs/n1vcx3po/4/

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        alert("you are at the bottom of the page");
    }
};
```

Comment: I Want to trigger the same function when the Dynamic div also reaches its end. how to achieve this? @Ajaiprakash

Comment: Did you try running this code? It should work anyway as we use variables that fetches value in the run time only.